# R: How to sample values under conditions from previous samples

Tags: r, nested, sampling, multiple-conditions

I have tried to wrap my head around this for a few hours now and my head just blanked eventually...
My end goal is a data frame with 26 rows and 4 columns, containing the values 1-6, distributed at semi-random, meeting certain conditions.

Conditions are:

1. Each number can only appear once within a row.
2. Neighbouring rows of the same column can never contain the same value.
   For this, column 1 and 2 must be seen as the same column containing 2 values, of which neither can repeat in a neighbouring row. So if I have "1 & 2" in one row of column 1 & 2, I can only have a combination between "3-6" in the next and previous row.
3. Values should be about equally distributed within any subsection of the table.

My original though was that I would sample a first row, then create a for loop to add the other rows one by one changing the probability for a number to be drawn based on the previous samples. Before adding this sample row I could checking that the second condition was met and if not resample.

I realised eventually that this is so nested that I can just not wrap my head around it... I assume that I need a while loop, which I have no experience with. As in while the first 2 conditions are not met, resample at a probability based on previous appearances. The problem is however that each column gets its own probability for each value based on the previous appearance, so I cannot just sample a row.
however if I sample each column individually based on the previous appearances, I will likely get the same values in a row...

So,  this is the conditions I would want as FALSE(I tried it with a function that would just repeat if the statement is TRUE):

```
temp[1] == table[i-1,1] || temp[1] == table[i-1,2] || temp[2] == table[i-1,1] || temp[2] == table[i-1,2]
temp[3]== table[i-1,3]
temp[4]== table[i-1,4]
```

here is how I could calculate the probabilities for sampling (I realise there is a problem if values did not appear yet as this would mean division by 0)

```
probAB <- rep(1,6) /table(table[,c(1,2)])
probC <- rep(1,6) /table(table[,3])
probD <- rep(1,6) /table(table[,4])
```

I you want to know what it is supposed to be: It is a non repeating chores rota, between 6 people where 2 people take up 1 chore, while the other 2 chores are done by only one person. I am open for alternative suggestions to achieve this^^

Answer (score 1):

We can use rejection sampling.  Just generate a sample for each row and if it meets the conditions accept it and go to the next row; otherwise, repeat.

```
nr <- 26
nc <- 4
k <- 6

set.seed(123)

is_ok <- function(x, y) all(x != y) && x[1] != y[2] && x[2] != y[1]

tab <- matrix(NA, nr, nc)
tab[1, ] <- sample(k, nc)
for(i in 2:nr) repeat if (is_ok(tab[i, ] <- sample(k, nc), tab[i-1, ])) break
```

Comment: Thank you, it did help me to get it in the end!

Here is the final code I used. Not the most elegant solution, but it worked.

```nr <- 26
nc <- 4
k <- 6

set.seed(123)

is_ok <- function(x, y) all(x != y) && x[1] != y[2] && x[2] != y[1]

tab <- matrix(NA, nr, nc)
tab[1, ] <- sample(k, nc)
for(i in 2:nr) repeat if (is_ok(tab[i, ] <- sample(k, nc), tab[i-1, ])) break

while (sd(table(tab[,c(1,2)]))> 0.6 || sd(table(tab[,4])) >0.6 || sd(table(tab[,3])) >0.6) {
  

tab[1, ] <- sample(k, nc)
for(i in 2:nr) repeat if (is_ok(tab[i, ] <- sample(k, nc), tab[i-1, ])) break

}```